# cannot resolve "No space left on device"

Tags: partitioning, disk, disk-usage, fdisk, disk-management

I'm installing one package while getting the error that `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device` However, I'm pretty sure my space is sufficiently empty and mostly unused.

---

**UPDATE**:
The result I get after running `df -h --exclude-type=squashfs`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.2M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda6       294G   27G  253G  10% /
tmpfs           7.6G  135M  7.5G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.6G     0  7.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7        32G   31G  5.6M 100% /home
tmpfs           1.6G   16K  1.6G   1% /run/user/120
tmpfs           1.6G  144K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

The result I get after running `df -i --exclude-type=squashfs:`

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            1971614    627  1970987    1% /dev
tmpfs           1980471   1287  1979184    1% /run
/dev/sda6      19570688 407691 19162997    3% /
tmpfs           1980471    166  1980305    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1980471      7  1980464    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1980471     18  1980453    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda7       2125760 634515  1491245   30% /home
tmpfs           1980471     24  1980447    1% /run/user/120
tmpfs           1980471     70  1980401    1% /run/user/1000
```

As you can see the root folder and home folder is only used left than 10%. So far I checked some sources and some answers suggest that it is because of `/tmp`. I tried to unmount but the problem persists. Can someone offer me some suggestions and possible solutions for it? Thanks a lot.

---

**NEW UPDATE**

output of du `-sh /home`:

```
du: cannot read directory '/home/lost+found': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/danni/.splunk': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/danni/.cache/doc': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/danni/.cache/netease-cloud-music/Cef/Cache/Local Storage': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/danni/.cache/netease-cloud-music/Cef/Cache/Cache': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/danni/.cache/dconf': Permission denied
30G /home
```

Comment: Can you replace that output with the output of `df -h --exclude-type=squashfs` and `df -i --exclude-type=squashfs`?

Comment: @muru Hi please refer to updated question.

Comment: /home seems to be 100% full .. Please update your question with the output of 
`du -sh /home`.

Comment: @SorenA question updated, thx.

Comment: you have set up `294G` for '/` and `32G` for `/home`. I would have done the other way round.

Comment: @RoVo oh god that's a terrible mistake, can I boot from the live system and redo partition?

Comment: @RoVo Cuz before I actually had the same problem with "`not enough space`" since I only had 20GB for `/` while too much space for `/media` so I resized it.

Comment: yes, 20G is just not enough, 32G should be fine, I'd go with 40G to make sure. You can resize partitions with [gparted started from a live usb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions?noredirect=1&lq=1).